# How to give "Share with" option while opening documents in iphone mail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction, cfbundleidentifier

So I've been going through the "[Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html)".
I've been able to achieve the "Open with myapp" option through Mail, was wondering how can I change the option to "Share with myapp" depending upon the file types specified?
This is what I've tried:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>                
</array>
```

Comment: Just to specify a bit more, I want to register my app for opening documents from any external application.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out from crawling other sites, the same cannot be done :-(